# Run JUnit test in a maven project that depends on javaee 6 api

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

Im trying to run a test that depends on Javaee6-api.
My pom setup is the following:

```
<project>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
         <version>6.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      [...]
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

When i run my JUnit test i get the following exception:

```
   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/event/FacesEvent
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)


        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    [...]
            org.eclipse

.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test error (JSF): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830299/unit-test-error-jsf-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abs)

Comment: I tryed this solution but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the following dependencie:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```